How to set ISO of android Ricoh Theta X using Java?
I am using THETA Plug-in to set iso for thetaX camera 360. 
However I didn't notice any changes on the camera.
This is code i tried:
import theta360.hardware.Camera;

int value = 50; // value of 50 to 3200 can be set.
Camera thetaCamera = ThetaCapturer.getThetaCamera(); // instance of Camera
Camera.Parameters parameters = thetaCamera.getParameters();
parameters.set(Camera.Parameters.RIC_EXPOSURE_MODE, Camera.Parameters.RIC_MANUAL_EXPOSURE);
parameters.set(Camera.Parameters.RIC_MANUAL_EXPOSURE_ISO_FRONT, value);
parameters.set(Camera.Parameters.RIC_MANUAL_EXPOSURE_ISO_REAR, value);
thetaCamera.setParameters(parameters);

Is there any solution for this?
Plugin version: 3.3.0, link: camera-plugin-api
Below are the documents I followed:
Theta-api-specs: iso-sensitivity
Theta-plugin-webrtc-sample: CameraOption
